# I want to run BST.linux (Brads spin tool) on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS If I cklick on it nothing happens

Tags: command-line, execute-command

I'm a TOTALLY newbee to linux. I want to emphasize that. TOTALLY. If something to do requires opening a window that is not directly visible on a freshly installed UBUNTU 16.04 LTS you have to describe ANY detail how to make it visible or anything else. Short answers like

"open console and type xyz.."

or 
"check for dependencies...."

will just result in new questions "How do I open a console?"
How do I check dependencies? etc.

I want to run Brads Spin Tool   BST.linux on my freshly installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  But nothing happends if I doublleclick on it. Nothing happens if I try right-click execute.

BST can be found here
http://www.fnarfbargle.com/bst.html

If it will be easier to use the BST for windows in combination with wine I will be happy too.

So please turn your knob "detailed explanations" to the max. 
thank you very much in advance

best regards

Stefan

Comment: http://forums.parallax.com/discussion/166585/total-linux-newbee-wants-to-run-bst-or-propeller-tool-on-ubuntu-16-4  You're asking the wrong question here and insisting on the "wine" tag (already edited out). You need a terminal. Either search for it in the dash or simply CTRL+ALT+T. Then follow the instructions already provided in the forum starting with adding support for 32bit -> `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`

Comment: Ok thank you for the gesture of answering at all. As you can read in this other forum I would have needED (past) DETAILED help. As nobody wants to take the effort for giving DETAILED help. I turn my back on Ubuntu and say good bye. You can close this question or delete it or do whatever you want. LOGOUT